# StageVideo comes on top of everything in Flex Mobile Project

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, air

I'm Building a mobile application with Flex (Air 3.3).
For Android there is sum nasty bug with stageVideo.
When I minimize the app when the stageVideo is playing or paused and open it again sometimes the stageVideo comes on top of everything. In my understanding that should be impossible because the stageVideo in a layer above the stage layer but it's happening. I don't have any clue how to fix this. I don't use any masks, I'm only attaching netStream.

Comment: Stage video actually sits in a layer below the display tree.  Its for that reason that you can overlay other displayobjects above it, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of why, you may be able to fix it simply by re-asserting its index in the DisplayList with [`addChildAt()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChildAt%28%29).

The only question left is when to call the operation.  I don't know about AIR, but you'd likely be looking for something akin to [`Event.ACTIVATE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#ACTIVATE).  If you can't catch an event to trigger the check, check periodically with either a Timer or [`Event.ENTER_FRAME`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#ENTER_FRAME)